# Movie about a tattooed guy who kidnaps people

Tags: story-identification, movie, horror

Saw it years ago but what I can remember there was a heavily tattooed guy who would invite people to a house party then cage them up and give them assorted piercings..then some people in the town hung him from a tree outside of town

Comment: Welcome to the site! Is there anything else you can add? I appreciate that you didn't write this question frivolously, I'm sure you tried to think of everything, but the more you put in the better. What country is this? Do you know where it was set (even just the country going by the characters' accents)? Any of the actors? Rough time period it's likely to have been released? Anything. Also, was it definitely a science fiction or fantasy work? If not, maybe [Movies & TV](http://movies.stackexchange.com/) is the place for you?

Comment: So, when he "gave them assorted piercings", does that mean things like lip-rings? Or attaching chains? Or impalement?

Answer (score 1):

I think this might be *[Strangeland](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strangeland_(film))*. The villain, "Captain Howdy", is indeed heavily into tattoos, piercings, and scarification, and he performs them on unwilling victims early in the film under the cover of inviting them to parties. He was found to be treatably insane and is eventually released, whereupon the townspeople indeed try to lynch him from a tree.

[image: Movie poster]